# My @POST statement is not being executed using Retrofit 2 in android

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to call an existing Web Api service in my android application using retrofit 2 library for login. When I debug everything seems to be fine except that my @POST line in the Service interface is not executed. I am using localhost and have forwarded the port, using port forwarding in chrome, to my phone.

Here is my code:
RestService.class

```
    public class RestService {

    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String url) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

ApiUtils.java

```
    public class ApiUtils {

    public static final String NService = "http://localhost:5108/NSureServices.svc/";

    public static Service getLoginDetails(){
        return RestService.getClient(NService).create(Service.class);
    }
}
```

Service.class

```
   public interface Service {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("GetLoginDetails")
    Call<User> login(@Field("USERID") String UserId, @Field("PASSWORD") String Password, @Field("apiKey") String ApiKey);

}
```

LoginActivity.class

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText email, password;
    Button login;
    TextView register, forgotPassword;
    Service service;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailIdEt);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordEt);
        register = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.signUpTv);
        forgotPassword = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordTv);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        service = ApiUtils.getLoginDetails();

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setUSERID(email.getText().toString());
                user.setPASSWORD(password.getText().toString());


                if(validateLogin(user.getUSERID(),user.getPASSWORD())){
                    doLogin(user.getUSERID(),user.getPASSWORD(),user.getApiKey());
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public boolean validateLogin(String UserId, String Password){
        if(UserId == null || UserId.trim().length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Username is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        if(Password == null || Password.trim().length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



    public void doLogin(String uid, String pwd, String apikey){
        try {
            Call<User> call =service.login(uid, pwd, apikey);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
}
```

My dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have already defined the apikey in the User data model.

Comment: even my @override is not being executed for onResponse and onFailure

Answer (score 0):

You missed slash at the beginning of you url

Your URL should be like this:

```
@POST("/GetLoginDetails/")
```

Also in your dependency, you have used support-v4 and v7 which is not necessary.

support-v7 included v4 support library so `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'` not necessary in your dependency.

Don't use + operator in your dependency version. User current version of support library.

Comment: can you try adding a slash at the end

Comment: I realized that retrofit was sending the request correctly and also fetching the required data. But my app response is unable to read the data correctly. I'm not sure why. Is it because the Transfer-Encoding is set as chunked? (Transfer-Encoding : chunked)